# Events in Blazor RenderTreeBuilder

Tags: blazor

I am having trouble using event binding on a Blazor component using the RenderTreeBuilder. I understand how to trigger events using the direct approach of writing the HTML and attaching an event to the component. However, I need to use the RenderTreeBuilder now.

Direct Approach

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="InputValue" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeyup="ChangeCounter" />
```

What I need to get to is something like the following:

```
public RenderFragment RenderContent => (builder => 
{
    int i = 0;
    builder.OpenElement(i++, "input");
    // Not an official property
    builder.AddEventCapture(i++, @bind-value, "InputValue");
    // Not an official property
    builder.AddEventCapture(i++, @bind-value:event, "oninput");
    // Not an official property
    builder.AddEventCapture(i++, @onkeyup, "ChangeCounter");
    builder.CloseElement();
});

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Quick note about the sequence numbering - it will work if your example since the sequence is deterministic. See https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3

Comment: @Quango You have a good point about it being deterministic. I do not think the UI changes based on input but that is a great thing to consider in the future if I were to need an undeterministic solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've improve a little bit on your html element and rest as follows:

```html
 <input type="text" @bind-value="InputValue" @bind-value:event="oninput" 
        @onkeyup="ChangeCounter" />

 <p>@InputValue</p>
 <p>@counter</p>

@code {

    public string InputValue { get; set; } = "Hello, Blazor";
    private string counter;

    private Task ChangeCounter(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        counter = args.Key.ToString();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Ran the code above and let the compiler produce this code below. See what the compiler is doing and imitate this. Note: The code should be in the `\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Razor\Pages\Index.razor.g.cs`, if you placed your Blazor code in the Index component.

```cs
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]
    public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        protected override void 
     BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder 
                                                                      __builder)
        {
            __builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
            __builder.AddAttribute(1, "type", "text");
            __builder.AddAttribute(2, "onkeyup",Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs>(this, ChangeCounter ));
            __builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.BindConverter.FormatValue( InputValue));
            __builder.AddAttribute(4, "oninput", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder(this, __value => InputValue = __value, InputValue));
            __builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
            __builder.CloseElement();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(5, "\r\n\r\n");
            __builder.OpenElement(6, "p");
            __builder.AddContent(7, InputValue);
            __builder.CloseElement();
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(8, "\r\n");
            __builder.OpenElement(9, "p");
            __builder.AddContent(10, counter);
            __builder.CloseElement();
        }
```

Note also how the compiler produce the sequence numbers. That is the correct way to do it...

Hope this helps...

Comment: You beat me to it (I had a conference call!). I always see what the compiler creates from `.razor` syntax to see how it can be done.

Comment: you beat me to it => This idiom means, I was going to say/do the same thing and you did it before I could. Thanks so much for letting me learn a new idiom. English is not my mother tongue. It's my third language...

Comment: No problem! Your answer was very good, I edited it slightly for layout/typos. In English we rarely use gender for "things", e.g. the compiler is an "it" not a "she" - but I could be wrong :) but you might ask Steve Sanderson or Ryan Novak ...

Comment: @enet thank you for the solution. I am still relatively new to blazor's RenderTreeBuilder.

Comment: @Quango, thanks for editing my answer. The editor often drives me crazy , so I left it as is. The use of "she" instead of "it", which is the correct word to speak of objects and animals was on purpose... Thanks.